# Parallel for с бесконечным циклом

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Есть класс для реализации фтп клиента с синхронизацией.

```
class FtpFile
    {
        private string md5;
        private string file;
        private string path;
        private string status;

        public string File
        {
            get { return file; }
            set { file = value; }
        }

        public string Status
        {
            get { return status; }
            set { status = value; }
        }

        public string Md5
        {
            get { return md5; }
            set { md5 = value; }
        }

        public string Path
        {
            get { return path; }
            set { path = value; }
        }
```

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопки в бесконечном цикле шла. Описываю `алгоритм`

1. Проверка доступности файла. Если файл никем не юзается, идем
   дальше
2. Проверяем md5 файла. Если он отличается, то грузим файл на
   сервак

   ```
   var listFtpFile = new List<FtpFile>();
   FtpFile ftpFile;

   for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       ftpFile = new FtpFile();
       ftpFile.File = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); // файл 123.txt
       ftpFile.Path = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); // путь /
       listFtpFile.Add(ftpFile);

   /*      if (Helper.IsFileReady(file))
           {
               var md5 = Helper.CalculateMD5Hash(file);
               if (ftpFile.Md5 != md5)
               {
                   ftpFile.Md5 = Helper.CalculateMD5Hash(file);
                   myFTP myFtp = new myFTP(host, login, password, "/");
               }
           }
   */
    }
   ```

Теперь стоит вопрос о том как правильно реализовать бесконечный цикл для `Parallel.For`. Не знаю, может есть лучшая конструкция просто на Thread-ах. Подскажите куда плыть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class ParallelUtils
{
    public static void While(Func<bool> condition, Action body) 
    { 
        Parallel.ForEach(IterateUntilFalse(condition), ignored => body()); 
    }

    private static IEnumerable<bool> IterateUntilFalse(Func<bool> condition) 
    { 
        while (condition()) yield return true; 
    }
}
```

Используем так:

```
Func<bool> whileCondFn = () => !_requestStopFlag;
ParallelUtils.While(whileCondFn, delegate()
{

});
```

Источник: [Implementing Parallel While with Parallel.ForEach](https://web.archive.org/web/20160625064021/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/08/12/9867246.aspx)